# Question regarding partial derivatives 1

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I'm trying to tackle the following question

> Let $f:\Bbb{R}^2\to\Bbb{R} \ , \ (x_0,y_0)\in\Bbb{R}^2 \ , \ \underline{u}=(u_1,u_2)\in \Bbb{R}^2$ where $\underline{u}$ is unit vector.
>
> Let $g(t)=f(x_0+u_1t,y_0+u_2t)$. Show that $D_{\underline{u}}f(x_0,y_0)=g'(0)$.

My try:
First, I think that it should be given that $g$ is differntiable at $x=0$. Now,
$$D_{\underline{u}}f(x_0,y_0)= \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f\left((x_0,y_0)+t\underline{u}\right)-f(x_0,y_0)}{t}=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac {f(x_0+u_1t,y_0+u_2t)-f(x_0,y_0)}{t} \\ g'(0)=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{g(0+t)-g(0)}{t}=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f\left(x_0+u_1t,y_0+u_2t\right)-f(x_0,y_0)}{t}$$hence, the claim is proven. Is my reasoning fine?

Please help, thank you!

Comment: You should post one of the questions in a separate post.

Comment: Actually your original 2 questions are closely related. It would have been better to leave them together. Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, yes, your reasoning is fine.

[For the second question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1215742/question-regarding-partial-derivatives-2/1215751#1215751), use the chain rule.

You have $g(t)=f({\bf r}(t))$ where ${\bf r}(t) = (x_0,y_0)+t{\bf u} = (x_0+tu_1,y_0+tu_2)$.

You are given that $f$ is differentiable. ${\bf r}$ is linear and thus differentiable. Thus $g$ is differentiable as well.

Notice that ${\bf r}'(t) = {\bf u} = (u_1,u_2)$. The chain rule states that $g'(t) = f_x({\bf r}(t)) u_1 + f_y({\bf r}(t)) u_2$.

Plugging in $t=0$ yields: $g'(0)=f_x({\bf r}(0))u_1+f_y({\bf r}(0))u_2 = f_x(x_0,y_0)u_1+f_y(x_0,y_0)u_2=\nabla f(x_0,y_0) \cdot {\bf u}$

You already know that $g'(0)=D_{\bf u}f(x_0,y_0)$ so done. :)